# Mass Changing Image in Crystal Reports

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

I want to change an image in about 110 CR 2008 Reports.

I've seen answer about mass changing fields, but I need to change image.
Is their any script or method I could use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you are saving the image in the database you can create schema xml file to reade from the image from DB and call this schema as subreport in the report itself.
the schema will be like this:
You have to make some modification on the id, target, element(table Name) and source as your requirements.

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <xs:schema id="rptAppSettings" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/AppSettings.xsd"   xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/AppSettings.xsd" xmlns="http://tempuri.org  /AppSettings.xsd" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-  microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:msprop="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop"   attributeFormDefault="qualified" elementFormDefault="qualified">
 <xs:annotation>
<xs:appinfo source="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdatasource">
  <DataSource DefaultConnectionIndex="0"   FunctionsComponentName="QueriesTableAdapter"     Modifier="AutoLayout, AnsiClass, Class,     Public" SchemaSerializationMode="IncludeSchema" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-  com:xml-msdatasource">
      <Connections>
      <Connection AppSettingsObjectName="Web.config" AppSettingsPropertyName="ConnectionString" IsAppSettingsProperty="true" Modifier="Assembly" Name="ConnectionString (Web.config)" ParameterPrefix="@" PropertyReference="AppConfig.System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.0.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionString.ConnectionString" Provider="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </Connections>
    <Tables />
    <Sources />
  </DataSource>
</xs:appinfo>
 </xs:annotation>
 <xs:element name="rptAppSettings" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true" msprop:Generator_DataSetName="rptAppSettings" msprop:Generator_UserDSName="rptAppSettings">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="App_Settings" msprop:Generator_UserTableName="App_Settings" msprop:Generator_RowEvArgName="App_SettingsRowChangeEvent" msprop:Generator_TableVarName="tableApp_Settings" msprop:Generator_TablePropName="App_Settings" msprop:Generator_RowDeletingName="App_SettingsRowDeleting" msprop:Generator_RowChangingName="App_SettingsRowChanging" msprop:Generator_RowDeletedName="App_SettingsRowDeleted" msprop:Generator_TableClassName="App_SettingsDataTable" msprop:Generator_RowChangedName="App_SettingsRowChanged" msprop:Generator_RowEvHandlerName="App_SettingsRowChangeEventHandler" msprop:Generator_RowClassName="App_SettingsRow">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="LogoImage"     msprop:Generator_ColumnVarNameInTable="columnLogoImage"   msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInRow="LogoImage"    msprop:Generator_ColumnPropNameInTable="LogoImageColumn"    msprop:Generator_UserColumnName="LogoImage" type="xs:base64Binary" minOccurs="0" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
       </xs:element>
      </xs:choice>
     </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
      </xs:schema>
```